# Statechart for active and inactive state

Tags: uml, statechart

I have a user with active and inactive state, where the administrator can make the user active (on recover) or inactive (on delete). My question is: 
1) Do I need to draw chart for this? 
2) If yes, Which one is the correct way of drawing statechart? a or b? or any other ways?

a) Start ----> User active  <----> User inactive 
b) Start ----> User active ----> User inactive ---> end 
   Start <---- User inactive ----> User active  ---> end

Answer (score 0):

I would say: no. A state chart is meaningful when you have to manage a complex state. And this is a trivial case. You can simply describe the state in the text of the use case. Usually this will result in different flow of actions in the activities of the use case (e.g. a decision that is name `Test state` and that exits with `[active]` or `[incative]`).